# How to allow Third party cookies or configure trusted domains in a webview of an Electron app?

Tags: electron, third-party-cookies, electron-webview

Some web services, eg Microsoft Teams, require allowing Third-party cookies or configuring trusted domains to perform a successful login, here is some documentation about it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-sign-in/sign-in-loop#resolution

But I can't find a way how to allow 3rd party cookies for a specific web view, or set the allowlist of trusted domains for cookies.

Does Electron provide any configuration for third party cookies in chromium's webview tag?